# Nutch Crawling Using Regex

Tags: regex, web-crawler, nutch

I wanted to crawl a website but save only those web pages ,
which are like :

Type A : http://mywebsite.com/page.html

any other links like. : http://mywebsite.com/a/b/ or http://mywebsite.com/a/
or any thing like this should be in queue to be crwaled , but they should be just used to get more url likes "type A" but not stored .

How to use regular expression in regex-urlfilter.txt in nutch .

or in RegexUrlNormalizer.xml

" I think that crawling on whole would be better option . But I also want that  while crawling . If a URL has anchor links like Type A : http://mywebsite.com/page.html  . I want to store that link A was obtained through this webpage. So after I crawl , I can remove pages and obtain only Type A pages and I have that, this type A webpage was obtained from what particular webpage .Can I configure nutch for doing so ? , If Yes , Some hints . Do I need to modify source code. Write my own plugin in nutch . ?"

Comment: Can you post some more examples of what things you are trying to match vs what things you don't want to match?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about nutch, but I can help with the regex. As per my comment above, right now it's now clear to me exactly what you want to match.

From the examples you have so far:

```
".*\.html" will match anything that ends ".html"
```

Comment: Hi saM . I want webpages like , - http://www.mywebsite.com/anything.html . So I think regex would be http://www.mywebsite.com/*.html .  What do u say ??

Answer (score -1):

You want http://mywebsite.com/a/b/ or http://mywebsite.com/a/ to get crawled and store only Type A urls ie. http://mywebsite.com/page.html ?

And its not clear what you mean by storing : is it about segments or crawldb ?
Note that if you crawl those pages to discover type A urls, the content WILL get stored in segments. You cant escape that.

My suggestion:
Crawl entire thing. Later on, remove the unwanted things by setting the regex urlfilter file and running [updatedb](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch_updatedb) and [updatesegs](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IntranetRecrawl) commands.

Comment: Sorry for late reply , I think that crawling on whole would be better option . But I also want that  while crawling . If a URL has anchor links like LINK A : http://mywebsite.com/page.html  . I want to store that link A was obtained through this webpage. So after I crawl , I can remove pages and obtain only Type A pages and I have that this type A webpage was obtained from what particular webpage .Can I configure nutch for doing so ? , If Yes , Some hints . Do I need to modify source code. Write my own plugin in nutch . ?

Comment: i have never heard of this being performed by nutch.. you need to modify the source code.